# How to Remove this Arrow or Image From IOS Listview in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

when i write a listview in xamarin forms this icon is auto added to IOS and this is not present in Android

i tried removing this using custom renderer by rendering viewrenderer but this this view renderer never gets call

here is the code which i used for custom renderering

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), 
typeof(StandardViewCellRenderer))]
namespace Sample.iOS.Renderers.RevisedRenderer
{
 public class StandardViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
  {
    public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, 
     UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        switch (item.StyleId)
        {
            case "none":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                break;
            case "checkmark":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                break;
            case "detail-button":
                cell.Accessory = 
          UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
                break;
            case "detail-disclosure-button":
                cell.Accessory = 
   UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
                break;
            case "disclosure":
            default:
                cell.Accessory = 
        UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
 }
```

let me know what need to be modified or add to make it work

Comment: try to use `item.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;`

Answer (score 1):

remove your switch, and leave the code like this:
var cell = base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv);

cell .Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

You can get more details at:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88286/xamarin-viewcell-how-to-turn-off-right-arrow-meant-for-touch-action

Comment: the problem is my native renderer does not even fire

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

> i tried removing this using custom renderer by rendering viewrenderer
>   but this this view renderer never gets call

The view renderer did get call in your project while the code inside `Switch statement` never executed, because `item.StyleId` is always null. You can add a breakpoint to check it.

**Solution:**

If you want to remove the arrow, just set `cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;` will work.

```
class StandardViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item,
 UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        Console.WriteLine(item.StyleId);

        cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;

   //     switch (item.StyleId)
   //     {
   //         case "none":
   //             cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
   //             break;
   //         case "checkmark":
   //             cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
   //             break;
   //         case "detail-button":
   //             cell.Accessory =
   //       UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
   //             break;
   //         case "detail-disclosure-button":
   //             cell.Accessory =
   //UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
   //             break;
   //         case "disclosure":
   //         default:
   //             cell.Accessory =
   //     UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
   //             break;
   //     }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

If you want to show cells with different `cell.Accessory` style, you can create a custom property instead of using `StyleId`.

I also uploaded a [demo here](https://github.com/XfHua/custom-cell-xamarin.forms).

Comment: again the same issue my viewrenderer in native never gets called

Comment: @RonakShethia Have you checked my demo? Or Can you share the code in your xamarin.forms project?

Comment: i worked actually i had two custom viewrenderer and that why the second renderer was not getting call i remove the second renderer and edited the code and its working now thanks